# How to handle data of multiple session using mvc in j2ee?

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

How to handle data of multiple session using mvc pattern in j2ee?
i was created web app which store data of session into db but this data will be displayed to other session that i don't want.

I want to manage data of multiple session and display data of that particular session which that has been entered into db..

for that  i'm using the logic of session management is it right??
i'm not sure of that please give me proper suggestion..

Answer (score 0):

Use the session id as a field in your database record when you want to store the data and query on the session id to display the data to your user.